# Group the same array element in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function to check for word sequences:

```
function sequence($arr_scheme = [], $arr_input = [])
    {
        $sequence_need = array_values(array_intersect($arr_scheme, $arr_input));
        if(!empty($arr_input) && ($sequence_need == $arr_input)):
            return true;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    }
```

There were my `sample` and `scheme` variables:

```
$sample = "branch of science";
$scheme = "The branch of science concerned of nature and property of matter and energy";
```

I have converted to array:

```
$arr_sample = explode(" ",trim(rtrim(rtrim($sample,".")," ")));
 echo 'Sample:';
var_dump($arr_sample);
```

[image]

```
$arr_scheme = explode(" ",trim(rtrim(rtrim($scheme,".")," ")));
echo '<br/>Scheme:';
var_dump($arr_scheme);
```

[image]

Now, I check the sequences:

```
$result = sequence($arr_scheme, $arr_sample);
```

The result:

```
echo '<br/>Result:';
var_dump($result);
```

[image]

When I set the variable `$sample` to
`"branch science"` the result will `return true`. This was fine.

However when I set the variable `sample` to
`"branch of science"` the result will `return false` .

Reason - the word `of` was more than 1, how I can solve this problem?

[image: word of **<code>of</code>** was more than 1 make this return to false]

Comment: May be `array_unique` can help?

Comment: Oh... ok I need to try it first.

Comment: No, with unique you will fail with other, like `property of matter`

Comment: The requirement is not clear. When should the function return `TRUE`? Describe all the rules or post more examples.

Comment: Word in sequence for example: if the sentence was "more" + "one". The word "more" should appear before "one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find first input word in the scheme (can be multiple).
Then run recursive for rests of arrays.

```
function sequence($arr_scheme = [], $arr_input = [])
{
  if (!$arr_input) return true;
  $first = array_shift($arr_input);
  $occurences = array_keys($arr_scheme, $first);
  if (!$occurences) return false;

  foreach ($occurences as $o) { // loop first word occurences
    $found = sequence(array_slice($arr_scheme, $o), $arr_input);
    if ($found) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

First word later occurences should not matter anything for match.
So, this tail-recursion function will work even better:

```
function sequence($arr_scheme = [], $arr_input = [])
{
  if (!$arr_input) return true;
  $first = array_shift($arr_input);
  $index = array_search($arr_scheme, $first);
  if ($index === false) return false; // not found
  return sequence(array_slice($arr_scheme, $index), $arr_input);
}
```

Comment: When I set the `$sample` to `"branch science concerned"` it will return false..it should be return true

Comment: Please test new answer.

Comment: So far so good. I will try many times... I accept this answer.

Comment: May be you get same results if just use `$o = reset($occurences)` instead of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can research more at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). Note: "Returns an array containing all of the values in array1 whose values exist in all of the parameters.". Then, look at in your result, when you call `var_dump($arr_scheme);`, you see "of" appears 3 times. and size of array result after compare is 5. however, size of array `$sample` is 3. So, you can understand why it returns false.

Solution for this case. why dont you try to use regular expression? or strpos function?

Comment: here is my code for test
`$mystring = 'The branch of science concerned of nature and property of matter and energy';
$findme   = 'branch of science';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). It computes the difference of arrays and returns the values in $arr_sample that are not present in $arr_scheme.

So,

```
array_diff($arr_sample, $arr_scheme)
```

will return an empty array if all the values in $arr_sample are present in $arr_scheme

The next step would be to count the length of the array returned by array_diff(). If it equals `0`, then we should return `true`

```
return count(array_diff($arr_sample, $arr_scheme)) === 0;
```

The above return statement could be presented as:

```
$diff = array_diff($arr_sample, $arr_scheme);
if (count($diff) === 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

From your comments it became clear that your function should return `true`
if all the elements of $arr_input are present in $arr_scheme in the same order
that they appear in $arr_scheme. Othewise it should return `false`

So,

`sequence(['branch', 'of', 'science', 'and', 'energy'], ['branch', 'of', 'energy'])`

should return `true`

and

`sequence(['branch', 'of', 'science', 'and', 'energy'], ['science', 'of', 'branch'])`

should return `false`

In this case the function sequence() could be defined as follows:

```
function sequence($arr_scheme = [], $arr_input = [])
{
    //test if all elements of $arr_input are present in $arr_scheme
    $diff = array_diff($arr_input, $arr_scheme);
    if ($diff) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($arr_input as $value) {
        $pos = array_search($value, $arr_scheme);
        if (false !== $pos ) {
            $arr_scheme = array_slice($arr_scheme, $pos + 1);
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sequence_need = array_unique($sequence_need);
```

array_unique removes any duplicate values in your array.. the duplicate 'of' will be removes.. Hope it helps..